# How to accommodate the wsdl changes of integration server in composite application framework?

Tags: webmethods

How to accomodate the wsdl changes of integration server in composite application framework (CAF) ?

Comment: I don't know what CAF is but your question seems unclear. Are you exposing a web service or are you consuming a web service in webMethods?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. If you're changing the signature of a web service operation that you've already created in CAF, just right click on it in the Bindings view and hit refresh. This will update the generated beans magically.
2. If you're adding/removing an operation from a web service (e.g. dragging a new flow service into a web service, and you've already added the web service into CAF) then it's a bit more annoying. Basically, CAF doesn't refresh the WSDL every time you add a new operation from it. You need to delete the WSDL file from your project and drag it in again.